# What is the verb form of "as you would have them do unto you"?

Tags: verbs, subjunctives, imperative-sentences

> Do unto others as you would have them do unto you.

How would linguists or grammarians characterize "would" in this saying, as far as English grammar rules go?

Comment: The sentence is an **imperative**. A degree of modal remoteness is expressed by the auxiliary "would", which in this case is used in its tentative sense, less direct and forceful than "will". It can be paraphrased as "You should treat others in the same manner that you would expect them to treat you in".

Answer (score 3):

*Will* is used here in its oldest sense, "want, desire", and cast in the past form as a 'subjunctive'—in this case, a subordinated hypothetical, which is semantically a sort of conditional. In conjunction with *have* it casts *have* as an 'experiential', as in "I had my paper accepted for publication".

Both the sense and the subjunctive are archaic uses (the passage is drawn from the Authorized Version of the Bible, published in 1611 and based on Coverdale's 1539 revision of Tyndale's 1525 translation). In modern use

- 'subjunctive' past forms ordinarily express some degree of unreality:

  > If I wanted him to behave differently I would tell him, *implying that I* don't *want him to behave differently*.
- volitive *will/would* survives only in a handful of situations, one of which is in condition clauses; but today it means "be willing to" rather than "desire":

  > If you'll bring sandwiches, I'll bring the beer.

You might paraphrase the sentence

> Treat others the same way you want to be treated by them.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this belongs here or over on [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) but I'll answer it anyway.

I would say that in this particular context it is a

**present positive conditional verb**

> If I were president (present), I would cut the cost of education (present conditional)
>
> If I had been president (past), I would have cut the cost of education (past conditional).
>
> If I were elected president next year (future), I would cut the cost of education (future conditional).

As you can see, the present and future tenses do not differ in the conditional part of the sentence

> I would cut the cost of education

But we can use the first part of the sentence to apply the second part to a context.

> If I were president (present)
>
> If I were elected president next year (future)

Breakdown of the original sentence.

> Do unto others (present) as you would have them do unto you (present)

Because the first part of the sentence is in present tense the **would** is a present conditional

See [here](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/would.html) for further reading.

Comment: I don't think there's any implication that it has a conditional interpretation. It's an imperative clause in which the first "do" is not present tense but a plain (infinitival) verb-form, as is normal with imperatives. The second "do" is not present tense, but again an infinitival verb-form as required by the modal auxiliary "would".